# How can I properly set sudo/visudo's editor?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ubuntu-10.04, sudo, sudoers

I am using Ubuntu 10.04 Server and trying to set up sudoers to respect a user's EDITOR choice (within limits)

In my sudoers I have:

```
Defaults        editor=/usr/bin/nano:/usr/bin/vim
Defaults        env_reset
```

And in the user .bashrc:

```
export EDITOR=/usr/bin/vim
```

$EDITOR is set:

```
$ echo $EDITOR
/usr/bin/vim
```

According to `man sudoers` this should be enough for $EDITOR to be set to vim:

```
editor  A colon (':') separated list of editors allowed to be used with visudo.
        visudo will choose the editor that matches the user's EDITOR environment
        variable if possible, or the first editor in the list that exists and is
        executable. The default is the path to vi on your system.
```

However `nano` is still being used for this user. A quick check of env:

```
$ sudo -- env | grep EDITOR
```

Returns nothing.

```
$ sudo -E -- env | grep EDITOR
```

Returns `EDITOR=/usr/bin/vim`

I am aware that I could do the following things to make EDITOR work:

- Set `env_editor`, `env_keep+=EDITOR` or any other option that keeps the EDITOR variable in sudoers: I don't want to do this as it could allow arbitrary execution of anything (e.g. `export EDITOR=~/bad_program_to_run_as_root`)
- Use `sudo -E` or even `alias sudo='sudo -E'`: Defeats the point of having `env_reset` and users without SETENV (not something I want to give out: see previous point) get `sudo: sorry, you are not allowed to preserve the environment`
- Set `editor=/usr/bin/vim`: But there are other users who don't know vim
- Use `sudo select-editor`: Close, but `sudo visudo` still opens in `nano`
- Just use sudoedit or vim directly: But then you lose the safety of tools like `visudo`, `vipw`, `crontab -e`.
- Just deal with it: Probably, but if I'm missing some insight I would love to know

I've also tried setting the `VISUAL` and `SUDO_EDITOR` variables (in desperation)

Is there something I have missed that will make `sudo visudo` open in the users editor of choice, without making the compromises above?

EDIT:

I think I understand why this isn't working as I expect. I'm putting it down here in case anyone else has the same misconception.

In the sudoers file

```
Defaults        editor=/usr/bin/nano:/usr/bin/vim
```

- Only refers to the list of editors that are allowed when running `visudo` (not any other program)
- `editor` checks $EDITOR, but if running `sudo visudo`, `sudo` does not set $EDITOR, so when `visudo` runs it will be empty
- Therefore the first editor is used, in this case `nano`

Can anyone confirm that this is correct?

I expected therefore that a safe solution would be to add:

```
Defaults!/usr/sbin/visudo env_keep+=EDITOR
```

i.e. keep EDITOR if and only if running visudo. This would then be checked against

```
Defaults                  editor=/usr/bin/nano:/usr/bin/vim
```

And if it didn't match either would use `nano`

Weirdly though, this doesn't seem to be the case:

```
$ sudo su - root
# export EDITOR=/bin/echo
# visudo
/etc/sudoers.tmp
visudo: /etc/sudoers.tmp unchanged
```

`/bin/echo` is used as the editor. Bug? Or another misconception?

Thanks

Answer (score 7):

You are right that setting the `EDITOR` variable should change the editor used for `sudo`. However, there are two other variables with precedence over the `EDITOR`: `SUDO_EDITOR` and `VISUAL`. Make sure none of them point to some other editor like `nano`.

Comment: The reason I upvoted is because so few answers make reference to `VISUAL` taking precedence over `EDITOR`.  I thought my `EDITOR` variable was just being ignored.  Turns out, in Centos7 both `EDITOR` and `VISUAL` seem to default to `pico`.

Comment: Another issue may be that your exported editor is not available in `$PATH` at `sudo` time. You could fix that by exporting the absolute path to the editor, like this: `set -u; EDITOR="$(which <your-editor>)"; export EDITOR; set +u`.

Answer (score 6):

There's another solution as described **[here](http://www.handsomeplanet.com/archives/60)**:

```
sudo update-alternatives --config editor
```

But it's not so friendly on a multi-user system as it only updates a symlink in `/usr/bin/`:

```
$ ls -l `which editor`
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 24 lip  4 19:37 /usr/bin/editor -> /etc/alternatives/editor

$ ls -l /etc/alternatives/editor
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 18 Jul  5 01:39 /etc/alternatives/editor -> /usr/bin/vim.basic
```

What happened to `select-editor` anyway? When I run it, it creates a file:

```
$ ls -l .selected_editor 
-rw-r--r-- 1 rld rld 75 Jul  5 01:54 .selected_editor

$ cat .selected_editor 
# Generated by /usr/bin/select-editor
SELECTED_EDITOR="/usr/bin/vim.basic"
```

But `sudo visudo` keeps using nano.

Answer (score 3):

In Debian 7, setting EDITOR in the environment didn't work.

To use Nano, I ended up adding the following line to `/etc/sudoers`

```
Defaults        editor="/usr/bin/nano"
```

Comment: WORKED LIKE A CHAMP on DigitalOcean Ubuntu 12.04. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you.  This also worked on Oracle Linux.  (I like nano/pico.)

Comment: Worked on Manjaro too `Defaults editor="/usr/bin/vim"`. It came configured with vi by default... vim comes with hard-core settings on though so... you know, use shift key to bypass visual.

Answer (score 2):

env_reset does not keep a user from setting variables on the command line:

```
$ sudo EDITOR=vim -- env |grep EDIT
EDITOR=vim
```

I find your findings about the `editor` option mildly shocking but unfortunately I don't know the answers to your secondary questions. One would think that the Ubuntu camp would have plenty of docs and configuration examples on this issue, perhaps we ought to look harder.